# Nested DO in FOR Loop in MS-DOS/Windows Batch

Tags: command-prompt, dos

I am trying to include multiple actions for each iteration of a FOR loop using nested DO statements. In essence, the intent is to combine both of the below lines into one.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (ArchiveList.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%destfolder%\%%~nxa" ECHO "%%~nxa does not exist"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (ArchiveList.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%destfolder%\%%~nxa" set /a i = i + 1
```

I tried using parentheses, as shown below...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (ArchiveList.txt) DO (IF NOT EXIST "%destfolder%\%%~nxa" DO(ECHO "%%~nxa does not exist" & set /a i = i + 1))
```

...but this results in the below error appearing for every iteration:

> 'DO' is not recongized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Appreciate any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `if` is `If boolean-condition something`

As "something" you have `DO(.....` which is not recognised as an executable command.

Remove the `DO(` and the final close-parenthesis.